# Having trouble displaying my questions from my database

Tags: python, sql, database, user-interface

Basically i've wrote a GUI, to make a maths game and have linked it to my microsft access database using sql, however i cannot get my questions to print to my label, any ideas ?. Also how do you generate a random number from my list of questions, as you can see my jim statement doesnt work.

```
import Tkinter
import Databaseconnector


class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        jim = randomnumber()

        SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tblQuestion'
        cursor = Databaseconnector.SELECT(SQL)
        rows = cursor.fectchall()
        for row in rows:
            print row.Question, row.Hint, row.A1, row.A2, row.A3, row.A4, row.CorrectAnswer
            alabel2.set("Question: " + (row.question)(jim).Item(1))

    def create_widgets(self):
        # create welcome label
        label1 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = "Question Game !")
        label1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'W')

        # create intruction label
        alabel2 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = "")
        alabel2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'W')

        a1loginbutton = Tkinter.Button(self, text = "Enter",)
        a1loginbutton.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = 'W')

        label3 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = "")
        label3.grid(row = 10, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'W')

        a2loginbutton = Tkinter.Button(self, text = "Enter",)
        a2loginbutton.grid(row = 11, column = 1, sticky = 'W')

        a3loginbutton = Tkinter.Button(self, text = "Enter",)
        a3loginbutton.grid(row = 9, column = 3, sticky = 'E')

        a4loginbutton = Tkinter.Button(self, text = "Enter",)
        a4loginbutton.grid(row = 11, column = 3, sticky = 'E')

        label4 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = "")
        label4.grid(row = 12, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'W')

        hiloginbutton = Tkinter.Button(self, text = "Hint",)
        hiloginbutton.grid(row = 13, column = 3, sticky = 'E')

        label5 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = "Score:")
        label5.grid(row = 14, column = 1, columnspan = 5, sticky = 's')

        def close_page(self):
            self.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.geometry("150x200")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited based on comments from OP:

1. There is a typo in this line: `rows = cursor.fectchall()`
2. Try changing the label.set statement to a simple case to confirm that this works. `alabel2.set("Question: " + row.question)`
3. What is the randomnumber() function, and what is the `(row.question)(jim).Item(1)` line supposed to return?

Comment: It is somethging i have written:                              DBfile ='E:\COMPUTING COURSEWORK\OI OI\FinallyWorking\Working\Mathsvaders.accdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ= ' +  DBfile)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#def dbconnect():
def SELECT(SQL):
    print(SQL)
    return cursor.execute(SQL)

Comment: i changed the cursor.fetchall thing, but its not letting me put it in the label